# Using streams Java 8 to modify in List Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Im new to Java 8. Im trying to build the studentlist here and i want to return the List by setting student name from the List of getStudentNames(). I want to split this String with space and loop each split words and assign each words(“orange”, “yellow”, “blue”) in withBadge below for every student name in the loop.

```
private static List<Student> buildStudentList(String badge) {
  //TODO: i want to stream the list of Splitted Strings here and modify the list below. 
  return getStudentNames()
                        .stream()
                        .map(name -> new Student.Builder()
                                .withName(name)
                                .withBadge(badge)
                                .build()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        protected static List<StudentNames> getStudentNames() {
            return List.of(“sam”, “andrew”, “joseph”);
        }
```

i tried something like below:

```
List<String> splitBadges = Stream.of(badge.split("\\s")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I tried with for each method on above list but it’s not working as i already have one more loop and want to return student list . It says expected void method and not able to return what I want .Can someone please help here with how to loop this ?

this is the sample output im expecting :

```
student: [
    {
      name: "sam",
      badge: "orange"
    },
    {
      name: "andrew",
      badge: "orange"
    },
    {
      name: "joseph",
      badge: "orange"
    },
    {
      name: "sam",
      badge: "yellow"
    },
    {
      name: "andrew",
      badge: "yellow"
    },
    {
      name: "joseph",
      badge: "yellow"
    },
    {
      name: "sam",
      badge: "blue"
    },
    {
      name: "andrew",
      badge: "blue"
    },
    {
      name: "joseph",
      badge: "blue"
    },
   ]
```

Comment: Got two questions here: 1) Do you expect the method to return a List that contains `["sam orange", "andrew yellow", "joseph blue"]` when invoked like `buildStudentList("orange yellow blue")`? 2) Are you trying to preserve or modify the List that `getStudentNames()` returns?

Comment: i had some corrections above . sorry for the confusion. i have attached the sample output im expecting... basically i want to loop over the split badges and assign each for every student name.

Comment: You are looking for `flatMap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (importing static `Collection.toList()`):

```
        Stream.of(badges.split("\\s"))
                .map(badge -> studentNames.stream()
                        .map(name -> new Student.Builder()
                                .withName(name)
                                .withBadge(badge)
                                .build())
                        .collect(toList()))
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(toList());
```

As pointed out in the comments, this can be greatly simplified and is a much better version:

```
Stream.of(badges.split("\\s"))
                .flatMap(badge -> studentNames.stream()
                        .map(name -> new Student.Builder()
                                .withName(name)
                                .withBadge(badge)
                                .build()))
                .collect(toList());
```

Comment: There is no need to do a `collect(toList())` in between, just to do `.flatMap(Collection::stream)` immediately after. Simply use `flatMap` instead of `map` in the first place.

Comment: above code works for me . if i remove collect(toList()), it is throwing an error "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context", not sure if its related. but it works fine with collect(toList()). any thoughts?

Comment: @shdu12 I believe Holger meant something like this: `Stream.of(badges.split("\\s")).flatMap(badge -> studentNames.stream().map(name -> new Student.Builder().withName(name).withBadge(badge).build())).collect(Collectors.toList());` which is more effective.

Comment: okay got it. thanks both for your help here !!